# I would have seen to it that I won

Tags: sentence-meaning

> If I were you, I would have seen to it that I won the prize.

What is the meaning of this sentence? I being a non-native English speaker, can't understand what it means exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see to it that something happens, it means you take the necessary action to ensure the mentioned result.

> See to it that you get those reports!

Means that I tell you to do what is necessary to get the mentioned reports.

> I will see to it that I deliver on time.

I will do whatever needs to be done to make the promised delivery.

> If I were you, I would have seen to it that I won the prize.

In your place, I would have made sure that somehow I would have won the prize.

Without context it is a little bit vague *what* someone would do to ensure winning that prize, the phrase might allude to cheating in order to get the prize, or it might simply state that the person spoken to should have tried harder (If I were you , I would have done my utmost best to win).